# Why is the nullspace of A a subset of the nullspace of PA for $PAx = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across a proof that contained the following.

$\text{A}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}\Rightarrow\text{PA}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$

Therefore, nullspace(A) $\subseteq$ nullspace(PA).

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in ker(A)$, then $Ax=0$, then $PAx=0$, this means that $x\in ker(PA)$, so $ker(A)\subset ker(PA)$.

Answer (score 0):

To show that one set is a subset of another, one must take an arbitrary element from the first set, and show it's inclusion in the second set.
$x\in nullspace(A) \implies Ax = 0 \implies PAx=P(0)=0 \implies x \in nullspace(PA)$

Answer (score 0):

the null space of $A$ is $\{x : Ax = 0\}$, and the null space of $P$ is $\{y : Py = 0\}$.

so take $x$ in the null space of $A$. Then $Ax = 0$. Since $P$ is linear $P(0)=0$, so $0=P(0)=P(Ax)=PAx$.

It follows that $PA(x)=0$ hence $x$ is in the null space of $PA$, as required.